# Hive - cannot resolve "month" given input columns

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to see how many papers were published each month in a range. I know that I need to group by month and then year but I keep receiving this same error saying "cannot resolve '`month`' given input columns". If I try to fix the month column, it goes on to do the same thing with the year and count columns. I've tried removing the aliases and just using the longer names but that also throws an error.

Comment: what error did you get if you use the longer names in the group by clause?

Comment: @mck 

AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'size(to_date(spark_catalog.default.metadata_2020_03_27.`publish_time`))' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires (array or map) type, however, 'to_date(spark_catalog.default.metadata_2020_03_27.`publish_time`)' is of date type.;

Comment: use `count`, not `size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(TO_DATE(publish_time)) AS month, 
    YEAR(TO_DATE(publish_time)) AS year, 
    count(1) 
FROM metadata_2020_03_27
WHERE (publish_time IS NOT NULL) AND (publish_time != "2020") AND (publish_time BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2021-12-31")
GROUP BY MONTH(TO_DATE(publish_time)), YEAR(TO_DATE(publish_time))
ORDER BY count(1)
```

`size` is used for finding the size of an array column, not for aggregation/counting. Use `count` for this purpose.